# Mocking a WebClient which takes in a non-string request and requires .block() method

Tags: java, junit, mockito, webclient, spring-webclient

I would like to mock a WebClient which takes in a class as a request and requires the .block() method to convert it from Mono to the required class.

This is the required method that we need to mock:

```
`response = webClientSample.post().uri(builder.toUriString())
                .headers(httpHeader -> httpHeader.addAll(httpHeaders))           .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(SampleRequest)).retrieve().bodyToMono(SampleResponse.class).block();`
```

This is what I have so far to mock (below code snippet), but I am getting a null pointer exception on the last line:
".body(BodyInserters.fromValue(SampleRequest)).retrieve().bodyToMono(SampleResponse.class).block();"

The only thing I can think of is that we need to mock the block() method.

```
Mockito.when(builder.path(any())).thenReturn(builder);
 Mockito.when(builder.toUriString()).thenReturn("url link");
 Mockito.when(webClient.post()).thenReturn(requestBodyUriSpec);
 Mockito.when(requestBodyUriSpec.uri(ArgumentMatchers.anyString())).thenReturn(requestBodySpec);
 Mockito.when(requestBodySpec.headers(httpHeader -> httpHeader.addAll(ArgumentMatchers.<MultiValueMap<String, String>>any()))).thenReturn(requestBodySpec);
    
 Mockito.when(requestBodySpec.body(ArgumentMatchers.any())).thenReturn(requestHeadersSpec);
 Mockito.when(requestHeadersSpec.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseSpec);
 Mockito.when(responseSpec.bodyToMono(SampleResponse.class)).thenReturn(Mono.just(populateSampleResponse()));
```

I've tried adding this line below (populateSampleResponse is a method which returns the class SampleResponse),

```
`Mockito.when(Mono.just(populateSampleResponse()).block()).thenReturn(populateSampleResponse()); `
```

But it triggers a method invocation error.

"org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException:
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);"

Comment: I think you've seen the limitations of mocking something like this and would suggest something like wiremock or mockwebserver that would serve you longer than trying to understand the intricacies of mocking an I/O client you did not build, just a suggestion.

Comment: did you try to use spy? instead of mock?